# How can I Invoke SAP SOAP webservices from Android? With username and password.?

Tags: android, web-services, sap-basis

When I run the program below I got the following exception in logcat:

> eclipse:02-17 18:33:35.254: WARN/System.err(608): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions targetNamespace='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>@1:686 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40554888)

Where can I append User Name and Password?

```
package com.venkat.pack;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class SOAPClientActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "Z_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Z_CUSTOMER_LOOKUP";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style";
    private static final String URL = "http://*********:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE193CF0AB8FEE64345/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=*****"; //this is my wsdl url.

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        Button btTest = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btTest);
        btTest.setOnClickListener(btTestListener);
        
        
    //whenever click the button 
    }
    
    public Button.OnClickListener btTestListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                
                
                // Create SOAP request
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                // Get response from envelope
                Object result = envelope.getResponse();

                // Display result
                Toast.makeText(SOAPClientActivity.this, result.toString(),
                        50000).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP allows the parameters sap-user and sap-password to be appended as URL parameters (as it does with sap-client). Try that, it should solve the problem.

Comment: I added the Username and password as Url parameter the fallowing url private static final String URL ="http://*********:****/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/srvc_14DAE9C8D79F1EE193CF0AB8FEE64345/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=*****&UserName=*******&password=******"; I got the fallowing Excxeption:02-24 12:37:44.159: WARN/System.err(530): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
02-24 12:37:44.159: WARN/System.err(530):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)

Comment: You should change the parameter "UserName" to "sap-user" and "password" to "sap-password".

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need call SAP webservice with basic authentication. Use `HttpTransportBasicAuth` insted of `HttpTransportSE` see the example below showing how to call `HttpTransportBasicAuth`

```
  HttpTransportBasicAuth aht = new  HttpTransportBasicAuth(url, username, password);
```

Let us know if it works or need more info.

Comment: When i i got the fallowing exception:02-08 17:58:20.084: E/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.microedition.io.Connector how can i resolveit?